# Issue with components rerendering in a Slider, when navigating through an array of these components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I'm trying to implement a custom slider component, that is 100vw long and has two components, one to the left and one to the right, overflowing offscreen at any given time. Looks something like this:

[image: img]

When the `Next` button is pressed, the screen translates X to the right 100vw, and when the `Previous` button is pressed, the screen translates X to the left 100vw.

Whichever way the screen moves, the `currentSlide` variable gets reassigned accordingly.

The issue that I'm running into, is that when I reassign `currentSlide`, all of these components get re-rendered.

Here is my slider component:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  SliderContainer,
  SlideLeft,
  SlideCenter,
  SlideRight,
  Button,
  ControlsContainer
} from "./styled-components";
import slides from "./slides";

export default function Slider() {
  const [currentSlide, setCurrentSlide] = React.useState(0);
  const previousButtonDisabled = currentSlide === 0;
  const nextButtonDisabled = currentSlide + 1 > slides.length;

  // if true, translate right,
  // if false, translate left,
  // if undefined, nothing is translating
  const [translate, setTranslate] = React.useState(undefined);

  const handleClick = React.useCallback(
    (isForward) => {
      setTranslate(isForward);

      setTimeout(() => {
        setTranslate(undefined);
        setCurrentSlide(isForward ? currentSlide + 1 : currentSlide - 1); // <-- the components re-render at this stage
      }, 1000);
    },
    [currentSlide]
  );
  return (
    <SliderContainer>
      <SlideLeft
        translate={translate}
        as={(currentSlide > 1 && slides[currentSlide - 1]) || null}
      />
      <SlideCenter translate={translate} as={slides[currentSlide]} />
      <SlideRight
        translate={translate}
        as={
          (currentSlide < slides.length - 1 && slides[currentSlide + 1]) || null
        }
      />
      <ControlsContainer>
        <Button
          disabled={previousButtonDisabled}
          onClick={() =>
            previousButtonDisabled ? undefined : handleClick(false)
          }
        >
          Previous
        </Button>
        <Button
          disabled={false}
          onClick={() => (nextButtonDisabled ? undefined : handleClick(true))}
        >
          Next
        </Button>
      </ControlsContainer>
    </SliderContainer>
  );
}
s
```

I know that I can just map through the whole `slides` array and render them all off screen and just translate X as many times as I want without a rerender, but what if I have 50 components? What if I have 100? What if they all have event listeners? That approach would pollute the DOM and client way too much.

Is there a way to cycle through `slides`, having only at most 3 components rendered at any given time? Whenever `currentSlide` changes, everything gets rerendered, and it could slow down the application, depending on how big the active 3 components are.

[image: muddy-currying-qczg9]

Comment: What exactly is the issue? That the three slides you *are* rendering are re-rendered when the state of `Slider` updates? This is how functional components work and you pass a different `as` component to "left", "center", and "right" slide containers every time `currentSlide` state updates, so the props of each changes as well. You could try maintaining an array of 3 elements and push/pop and shift/unshift from the ends, but I am not sure how well this may work with your established transitions.

Comment: Yes that my issue. As far as your suggestion goes, I'd imagine I'd still see a rerender of each component because, as you said, my transitions are dynamically assigned. I haven't been able to figure this out, I guess it's not possible to approach this without seeing rerenders.